# How to load data from store to Form.Panel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a form.Panel in which I show some data. I receive the data as XML from the server and load it directly into the fields using

```
podform.getForm().load({url:url_servlet+'kadastr_zemform.jsp' ...
```

along with a XMLReader.

Now I want to show the data in 3 separate form.Panel. But I just wan't to load the data once before loading it into panels. I guess form.load() no longer works for me in that case.

How would I load the data into several panels? Should I use a store cause I also need to be able to edit the data and send it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find two solutions with store.

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({                
            url: url_servlet+"kadastr_zemform.jsp",
            reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({
            totalProperty: "results", 
            record: "contact",
                            fields: [
                                    ]})
});
store.load();
```

1. You can use

   ```
    podform.getForm().setValues(store.getRange(0)[0].data);
   ```
2. Or this:

   ```
   var record = store.getAt(0);
   podform.getForm().loadRecord(record);
   ```

This answer takken from sencha forum. http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?248760-How-to-load-data-from-store-to-FormPanel&p=912235#post912235

Answer (score 0):

You could work with one main form panel that contains 3 sub-panels with the fields you need. Then if you call load() on the form, the fields will be initialized also if they are into different sub-panels (because are elements contained into the main form):

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel',{
   layout: 'vbox',
   items: [
   {itemId: 'panel1', xtype: 'panel', layout: 'form', items: [{xtype: 'textfield', name: 'text1'}
   ]},
   {itemId: 'panel2', xtype: 'panel', layout: 'form', items: [{xtype: 'textfield', name: 'text2'},
   {itemId: 'panel3', xtype: 'panel', layout: 'form', items: [{xtype: 'textfield', name: 'text3'}]
});
```

Otherwise if you cannot manage only one form panel with subpanels, you should consider to manage the Ajax call directly (using Ext.Ajax.request) and then use the resulting object to init each form.